# SVG Path half circle (raphael)

Tags: svg, path, raphael

I'm trying to create an inner circle which is placed at the bottom of a complete circle. I've been trying to create it using `paper.path()`.

Here is the example [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BjkU9/2/)

```
paper.path("M32,180 L248,180 a15,10 8 0,1 -215,0 z");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `sector` function like this:

```
sector(140, 140, 116, 200, 340, {})
```

returns almost what you want. Just replace the first *move to* command to move to the first point of the arc instead of the center of the circle and you are good to go.

Replace

```
return paper.path(["M", cx, cy, "L", x1, y1, "A", r, r, 0, +(endAngle - startAngle > 180), 0, x2, y2, "z"]).attr(params);
```

with

```
return paper.path(["M", x1, y1, "L", x1, y1, "A", r, r, 0, +(endAngle - startAngle > 180), 0, x2, y2, "z"]).attr(params);
```

and you get:

```
paper.path("M30.995655988834628,179.67433662577756L30.995655988834628,179.67433662577756A116,116,0,0,0,249.00434401116536,179.67433662577756z");
```

which seems to be what you're after.

Comment: It is indeed, may i ask you where did you learn this ? i've struggle over 10 hours trying to understand the "A"on svg's

Comment: I found Rafael's [pie chart example](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html) and recognized your `sector` function. Then I tried to use `sector`, tweaked the values to center it and the result was very close. Then I googled `svg path` to refresh my memory on what `M`, `L`, `A` and `z` meant and it became pretty clear that you shouln't _move to_ the center but rather directly to the starting point of the arc. Bingo!